# GAE: In mail HEADER UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, ascii, decode

UPDATE:
I've figured out that when Gmail is autoforwarding incoming emails then it will keep the emails original header which is not displayed by my code but will raise error. With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13152996/1863061) I've managed to get the header. **How can I avoid it from raising exception because non-Ascii email header?**. Solution where I can just ignore it is also welcome!

ORIGINAL POST:
I've this annoying problem with **UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position...**. I've tryed out many things since many asked similar question but none of the solutions work here. The code works great for non-ASCII.

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
from google.appengine.api import mail


class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):

        tobesent = mail_message.subject
        logging.info(mail_message.subject)
        logging.info(mail_message.date)
        tobesent = ''.join(c for c in tobesent if c.isdigit())

        mail.send_mail(
            sender="senderaddress@gmail.com",
            to="receiveraddress@gmail.com",
            subject="hello bello",
            body= "fontos informacio: " + str(tobesent)
        )

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

The error I get in my GAE Logs is the following:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/mail_handlers.py", line 69, in post
    self.receive(mail.InboundEmailMessage(self.request.body))
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 743, in __init__
    self.update_from_mime_message(mime_message)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1305, in update_from_mime_message
    super(InboundEmailMessage, self).update_from_mime_message(mime_message)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1214, in update_from_mime_message
    super(EmailMessage, self).update_from_mime_message(mime_message)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1094, in update_from_mime_message
    subject = _decode_and_join_header(mime_message['subject'], separator=u'')
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 559, in _decode_and_join_header
    for s, c in email.header.decode_header(header))
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 559, in <genexpr>
    for s, c in email.header.decode_header(header))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tryed out all solutions found on the internet such as `.encode('utf8')` or `decode.encode('utf8')`, or `unicoded = unicode(non_unicode_string, source_encoding)`
where source_encoding is something like 'cp1252', 'iso-8859-1' etc., and sending this to output (by Daniel Beck) so I hope this is no duplicate but then what is the solution? Nothing works.

Here is what happening: I receive an automated email to my Gmail account which is forwarding it automatically (at filter settings) to my me@myapp.appspotmail.com . The email contains áéíőűöüó letters also in subject also in body. That is the problem. That will make the whole thing fail. 
I've tryed outgoing email settings in Gmail **Use Unicode (UTF-8) encoding for outgoing messages**. That will only work if I manually forward the email.

app.yaml in case:

```
application: myappid

version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /_ah/mail/myaddress@myappid.appsportmail.com
  script: myappid.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: myappid.app

inbound_services:
- mail

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: Please show the actual code, the error is happening in the subject but your code shows you setting the subject manually to "hello hello".

Comment: Also read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) and [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: No. This is the actual code. This will give the same. I believe the error comes from inside `def receive`

Comment: It does, but it only happens if you actually use unicode characters inside the subject, which your sample code doesn't. Plus, you mention in your description that you have those characters in your subject, but you don't show it. Please show how you are doing that.

Comment: This is the subject of that automated email: rendszergazda:tessék bejelentkezni a megadott címen (kötelező)   # as you see in position 18 indeed there is 'é'. Although if I will just copy this email and send it from the same email address it will work as expected. I don't get it why. I update the question now.